# O que fazer com links para conteúdo em outras línguas?

Tags: debate, postagem

Muitas questões ou respostas possuem links para conteúdo em inglês aqui no SOpt. Deve haver alguma limitação quanto a isso?

E a indicação de livros? Algum problema em usar links para sites comerciais do Brasil ou outro país?

Sabemos que a qualidade do conteúdo disponível em português é baixa em sua maioria. Os artigos da wikipedia costumam ser bem piores que a versão em inglês, os blogs e outros meios de publicação são bem fracos, muitas vezes fruto de boa vontade mais do que capacidade de dizer algo relevante e mesmo os livros, originais em português ou traduções, são problemáticos, alguns sendo temerários.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minha opinião é que deve ser permitido já que muito conteúdo importante e relevante só está disponível em inglês. Isso vale para qualquer conteúdo, inclusive livros.

Sempre deve haver algum indicativo, algo como (EN), quando isso ocorrer. O leitor deve ter ciência de que está indo para um conteúdo em inglês antes de clicar.

Outras línguas pelo menos deveriam ser bastante evitadas, quantas línguas devemos saber para conseguir o que queremos? Claro que pode-se usar um tradutor mas mesmo assim o ideal é que isso seja caso extremo. De qualquer forma, duvido que aconteça com frequência mesmo se o uso for o espanhol que é mais ou menos compreensível por muitos.

Um dos principais motivos para a criação do SOpt é facilitar que os usuários possam se expressar em português e tenham conteúdo de qualidade na nossa língua. Algumas pessoas até questionam se devia ter um SO em português, alguns até de forma preconceituosa e arrogante. Mas não saber nada de inglês pelo menos para leitura de artigos técnicos e documentação certamente compromete a capacidade de qualquer profissional de evoluir em sua profissão. Isso nunca esteve em debate.

Outro detalhe importante é que independente da língua que esteja, postagens que praticamente só contenha um link continuam altamente indesejáveis.

Acho que deveria sempre se tentar algo de qualidade e tentar oferecer pelo menos uma alternativa em português, porque algumas pessoas não conseguem ler nada em inglês, apesar de isso estar longe do ideal profissionalmente.

Sintam-se livre para discordar.

Comment: Sobre o último parágrafo, acabo de abrir uma discussão à parte: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: Apoio a ideia de ter um indicativo -- sugiro (em inglês) -- para ficar claro que o conteúdo é inglês.

Comment: @bfavaretto Agora você roubou minha questão :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Será que precisamos mesmo de <sup>(en)</sup> pra todo lado?

Tenho visto (e usado) isso bastante, mas está começando a me incomodar. Fica muito poluído visualmente! Será que não seria melhor flexibilizarmos isso, mantendo somente em tag wikis (que são um conteúdo mais documental, digamos)?

Pontos a se pensar:

- Me parece que boa parte dos links que temos colocados em perguntas e respostas são para materiais em inglês.
- Documentações oficiais geralmente estão em inglês (quando há tradução, costuma ser automática e/ou ruim). As pessoas já esperam que esse tipo de conteúdo esteja em inglês.
- Imagino que programadores que não sabem inglês já estão acostumados a cair em conteúdos nessa língua. Será que a falta de um <sup>(en)</sup> vai deixá-los tão chateados assim?

Comment: Concordo muito. E faz sentido manter nas tag wikis. E para o restante: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169271/147423

Comment: acho educado sinalizar o idioma antes do link, já que dá a opção ao leitor de saber, de antemão, se quer ou não ler aquilo. Daí a ser obrigatório, é outra discussão.

Answer (score 0):

Muitos recursos não existem em português. A grande maioria é inferior em português.

E, para quem for como eu, não acho que consigo procurar conteúdo em português, não tão bem quanto em inglês.

Nem começo a pensar em **livros** em português...

Assim, acho que é necessário permitir referências em inglês.

Então uma resposta que só fica completa com a informação em um site inglês (ou pergunta do SO!) é aceitável.

**Mas e se o OP não fala inglês?** Nem lê. Uma coisa é procurar resposta no google, cair aqui, ver um link em inglês e não entender. Acontece. Talvez até incentive alguém a tentar entender o inglês.

Mas é frustrante para o OP receber uma resposta que não pode entender, ou sequer decifrar.

Tampouco acho sensato postar um link para uma resposta perfeita (em um comentário talvez), e ficar perguntando "você entende inglês? Senão, posso traduzir".

Bom, finalmente, o que quero propor é uma opção ou item no perfil dos usuários, ou mesmo uma checkbox na pergunta indicando se o OP aceita/quer links em inglês. Fica melhor se soubermos que não adianta postar um link em inglês.

Fica mais educado do que perguntar se o OP entende, e muito melhor que postar uma informação inacessível para o OP.

Será que devo abrir uma pergunta para isso? Me pareceu que cabia aqui.

Comment: Eu não vejo problemas em postar links para informações inacessíveis ao OP, porque [as respostas aqui não são só para o OP](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4007/74). É claro que o link deve ser um conteúdo complementar, uma referência. Respostas devem responder a pergunta sem depender dos links externos, caso contrário deveriam ser comentários.

Comment: Concordo... é só que quando a informação é muito relevante e extensa (não pode caber na resposta), fico tentado a perguntar se o OP entende... porque não acrescenta se não for o caso. É mais uma delicadeza com o OP, isso é.